# Python Selenium Browser Windwow does not open

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I tried to open the page https://www.youtube.com/ with selenium wia the gecko Driver but no window opens here is the Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(r'C:\Users\janzi\Desktop')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you get any error message.

Comment: @JanZickel Do you see any error?

Comment: no i dont get any error

Comment: don't you get error message when you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? It may need to install `geckodriver.exe` from [download](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0). And it would need path to this driver `Firefox(r"C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')`

Comment: give full path of firefox driver